# Access static property in another class's non-static constructor in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to access a static property of a normal class (ClassA.StaticPropertyXX) in another class's non-static constructor. ClassA is a normal class.

It works fine. I need to know if its the right way.
Please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Probably no issues if done right...

Comment: Yes and it works fine. But Im not sure if its right to do it this way.

Comment: Instead of posting a question, you could have tried and made several different attempts in the same time.

Comment: Then why didn't you ask that?

Comment: @Deefa There are plenty of reasons why this is the wrong way. If the construction of the class relies on a value, instead of hard-coding the value as a call to a static member, create a constructor that takes a parameter. This is what they are there for.

Comment: agree with @AdamHouldsworth, its better to create parameterised constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
class MyClass
{
    private int _value;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _value = OtherClass.StaticInt;
    }
}
```

Favour:

```
class MyClass
{
    private int _value;

    public MyClass(int valueForConstruction)
    {
        _value = valueForConstruction;
    }
}
```

Decouples `MyClass` from `OtherClass`, even if you do this:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass(OtherClass.StaticInt);
```

Comment: I actually need to set the static value and use it somewhere else.

Comment: @Deefa Then simply use the static as the constructor argument.

Answer (score 0):

There will be nothing preventing you from doing so. You'll just have built in coupling between these classes. Changes to ClassA may affect (even break) the other class. So you should avoid it if you can.

Answer (score 0):

What you may encounter:

- You don't have a `using` statement for the namespace, so `ClassA` is not available. This can be solved by either adding the `using` statement or specifying the full namespace.
- The name `ClassA` conflicts with another name. That can be solved by creating an alias for a namespace in a `using` statement.
- The static property is not `public`.

As long as you have access to the `ClassA` type, you can access the public static properties in it.

Comment: Thanks Guffa. So the code I've written is fine. I have ClassA in the same namespace and have access to it.

Comment: @Deefa: Yes. It's not so usual to access properties that way, so it naturally rises the question if there might be a better solution. :)